# gcc48 (downloaded from homebrew) cannot find stdio.h

Tags: c, gcc, homebrew

I am working on OSX Yosemite and I installed `gcc-4.8` from homebrew.

The following program fails upon compilation (e.g. `gcc-4.8 main.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello world");

    return 0;
}
```

with the error :

```
main.c:8:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

and

```
 $`gcc-4.8 -print-prog-name=cc1` -v
```

yields

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/lib/gcc/4.8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0/4.8.4/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/lib/gcc/4.8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0/4.8.4/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/lib/gcc/4.8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0/4.8.4/include-fixed
 /System/Library/Frameworks
 /Library/Frameworks
End of search list.
```

and

```
$ find /usr/local/ -name "stdio.h" -print
```

yields

```
/usr/local//Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/local//Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0/5.2.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
/usr/local//Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/local//Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/lib/gcc/4.8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0/4.8.4/include/ssp/stdio.h
/usr/local//include/c++/4.8.4/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/local//lib/gcc/4.8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0/4.8.4/include/ssp/stdio.h
```

Now I know I can pass `-I /path/to/directory` to get the compiler to find the correct header files, but for goodness sake this is `stdio.h`!  I don't want to have to do this for silly little programs.  How can I fix this flaw?

Comment: Have you got XCode installed? And the command line utilities for XCode? There's a modest chance that the command line utilities will put the headers in situ (into `/usr/include`, in other words). XCode hides its headers off in lala-land somewhere. When I run `clang -v` to compile a file, it lists `/usr/local/include`,
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include`,
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include`,
`/usr/include` — but I installed the command line tools.

Comment: That raises another point... Why use `gcc` when XCode installs a perfectly usable, in fact even-more-functional compiler (you'll have better leak checking software, for example)...

Comment: Seb - Good question.  Because I am used to developing code with gcc and I would prefer to work develop code with a compiler (and options) that I am familiar with and that is easily available on Linux, as well as, OSX.  Another complaint is that clang by default usurp's the OSX's gcc command, when in fact it is not gcc.  That fundamentally angers me.

Comment: As other Jonathan says, you need the "command line utilities for XCode" to provide the C library headers in `/usr` (and to provide the assembler and linker, I think).

Comment: Jons - I did recently upgrade from Mavericks to Yosemite.  I know previously I had XCode installed, but I'll check this evening.  Perhaps the upgrade broke that functionality.

Comment: Yes, I do have the xcode command line tools installed, the clang compiler (i.e. `/usr/bin/gcc main.c`) compiles fine.

Comment: in clang, you have to set all the include search directories and the library search directories.  The defaults (nothing) will not work.  It reads like you have some more setup to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing the brew formula and reinstalling it.  It now works, I'm still not clear as to where / when it got corrupted.

**EDIT**
Turns out this issue has occurred for me several times now.  It happens every time that I upgrade OSX or Xcode.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Sierra and have reinstalled twice to no avail.